# Python: How can I output the datacompy.compare.report to a text or csv file? I can only see it in the terminal, need a file

Tags: python

I have everything working and get the comparison in the terminal and seems to be exactly what i need, but I would love to be able to create a file from this script.  I've searched and searched and searched, and can not find out how to do it.  Basically, i want the output of the compare.report to go to a file.  Please any assistance is greatly appreciated.  I feel I am SO close, just need this final piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `report()` returns a string (see the [docs](https://capitalone.github.io/datacompy/api/datacompy.html#datacompy.core.Compare.report)), you can just write that returned value to a file (see [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)), e.g.:

```
import datacompy
...
compare = datacompy.Compare(...)
...
with open('report.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(compare.report())
```

Comment: Wow, thank you SO much, that got it working (once I added utf-8 encoding to the file), I was able to create a csv successfully!!!

Comment: /Is it possible to have it in a proper tabular structure rather than just a string?

Comment: @Duffer You could get the data you are interested in (i.e. with the help of the [datacompy convencience methods](https://capitalone.github.io/datacompy/pandas_usage.html#convenience-methods)), and write that data to CSV (i.e. using [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)).